# Leaks reporting issue with NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

Any idea why `sendSynchronousRequest` is causing a leak below?  Instruments states that the responsible frame is `NSURLConnection` and it points at a `NSCFString` leaked in the line with `sendSynchronousRequest`.

I've read that this was a known issue before OS 2.2 or something, but should definitely be fixed now.  Any thoughts?

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/api/v1/dosomething"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *bodyData;

[request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *body = @"test";
bodyData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
[body release]; 

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Using a synchronous connection is pretty horrible anyway. You're blocking the main thread while running a potentially long network operation.

Comment: What Mike says is generally good advice, but just to nuance it -- you're blocking the calling thread, which might not be the main thread.

Comment: @Mike thanks for the tip, but I'm totally aware and this certainly isn't the "main" thread.  This is a background thread and I actually do need a synchronous result to continue this thread.

Comment: OK, but in which case you are calling UIKit methods from a background thread, which is generally unsafe, and likely to cause you a crash one day

Comment: Good point.  I'll move the networkActivityIndictorVisible method over to the foreground thread.  I didn't even think about that in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem in my project. I write a new method, and this method makes asynchrousRequest. After that I call the method like this; performSelector.... waitUntilDone:YES . It worked for me, at least leaks are decreased.

Comment: I've debated trying this...  Good to know if I do take this approach it will work.